# Replace shortcut with relative symlink in nested folders

Tags: powershell, symlink, shortcut

I need help to convert all the Windows shortcut to relative soft links (symlinks) with PowerShell.
All the original files (targets of the shortcuts) are on a single folder, and inside it there is another folder with files, shortcuts and other folders (that can contain other files, shortcuts and folders).

What I'm looking is thus make this command for every shortcut (with eventually more `../`):

```
cmd /c 'mklink "path/shortcut.txt" "../file.txt"' && del "path/shortcut.txt.lnk"
```

With this code I can get the absolute path of the target of the shortcut:

```
dir * -Include *.lnk -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
  $fullpath = $sh.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath
}
```

Any help? How can I make it find the path and the number of `../` needed?

Comment: `Resolve-Path -Relative`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that. Shortcuts provide more functionality than just the path to some file.

Comment: I need symlinks because they works on linux and other programs (like FTP) and also they can be have relative path.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks! That helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found how to do it. This is the script:

```
$obj = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;
dir * -Include *.lnk -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $obj.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath -Replace '.*\\'
    $name = $(Resolve-Path -Relative $_) -Replace '^\.\\' -Replace "\.lnk$"
    $rel = '';
    for ($i=0; $i -le ([regex]::Matches($name, '\\' )).count; $i++) {
        $rel = $rel + '..\\'
    }
    cmd /c mklink "$name" "$($rel + $file)"
    del "$($name + '.lnk')"
}
```

Comment: It just replaced all the files with symlinks to "". Thank you bro. 6 hours of work flushed down the drain.

Answer (score 0):

@huh-hulk, these sort of things that perform bulk operations on files or folders, are extremely precarious when run without being rigorously tested. you were supposed to test this on an isolated group of experimental/throw-away files and folders before you attempt it on your real files and folders :(

to clarify again for those who might end up indiscriminately wiping off massive amounts of their Windows Lnk shortcuts, this is what the original poster's PowerShell script is doing:

___Suggested FileName:
Convert Windows Lnk Shortcuts to Symbolic Links.ps1

```
# Create a WScript.Shell COM object
$obj = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;

# Get all files with a .lnk extension recursively in the current directory
dir * -Include *.lnk -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    # Extract the target path from the shortcut file using WScript.Shell
    $file = $obj.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath -Replace '.*\\'

    # Resolve the relative path of the current .lnk file
    $name = $(Resolve-Path -Relative $_) -Replace '^\.\\' -Replace "\.lnk$"

    # Initialize an empty string for the relative path
    $rel = '';

    # Calculate the relative path based on the number of backslashes in the target path
    for ($i=0; $i -le ([regex]::Matches($nomeok, '\\' )).count; $i++) {
        $rel = $rel + '..\\'
    }

    # Create a symbolic link using mklink with the resolved relative path and target file
    cmd /c mklink "$name" "$($rel + $file)"

    # Delete the original .lnk file
    del "$($name + '.lnk')"
}
```